# When does $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\infty \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)-g(x) = \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose $f,g$ are real continous function and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = \infty$. When does $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\infty \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)-g(x) = \infty$?

---

So in other words I am looking for a result to determine that $f$ "grows faster" than $g$. Say for instance I am looking at $h(x) = x^7-100x-\log(1+x^{50})$ with $f(x) = x^7$ and $g(x) = 100x+\log(1+x^{50})$. I would like to compare them as a fraction as then we have L'Hopital's rule or statements about exponential growth vs polynomial growth etc.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What about $f(x)=2x$ and $g(x)=x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true as stated now. Set $\alpha(x) = f(x) / g(x) $. Then

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) -g(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \alpha(x) g(x) - g(x) =\lim_{x \to \infty} (\alpha(x) -1) g(x) = \infty $$

Because both terms of the product have limit equal to infinity.

Comment: Thank you very much, just what I was looking for :) I assume you don't actually need your functions to be continuous then?

Comment: No, it's not needed! As you see, the crucial hypothesis is that $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = c$ exist and it is $\neq 0$: in this case the product splits as $\infty \cdot c = \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot prove it, since it is not true. Just take, for instance $f(x)=e^x+x$ and $g(x)=e^x$.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question and add some more context then

Comment: Do you mean that you will change your question in such a way that my answer will not be an answer anymore?

Comment: Yes, I am afraid so. But thank you for the initial answer :)

Answer (score 0):

$g(x) = 100x+\log(1+x^{50}) < 100x + \log(2x^{50}) = 100x + \log 2 + 50 \log x < 100x + 50x+\log2$ as $\log_{10} x < \ln x < x$ for all $x > 1$.

Thus you are comparing $x^7$ to $150x$, which means that the first grows faster.